# Solr Query Wildcardquery in exact Searchstring

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I would like to do a wildcard query with the following configuration in the schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="textGeneral" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The data i would like to find is the `The Frick Collection, New York.`

When I do the following query `q=image_copyright:"frick collection,"` everthing works great.

But when I try to add wildcardsearch `q=image_copyright:"*ck collection,"` I dont get any results.

Does anyone know how to do this with the NGram Tokenizer who slows up indexing time.

**Edit 2012/04/19**  I realized that you can do something like this. `q=image_copyright:*ck?collection,*` But this not 100% correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the well known issue of wildcard queries not being analyzed see [here](http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/a6b9144ecab9d0ff/search_phrase_wildcard).

As of 3.6.0, recently released, this should be fixed

Answer (score 2):

Solr 4.8 added support for "Complex Phrase Queries", which include quoted wildcards.